# Java/Jmeter add 15 seconds to epoch

Tags: javascript, java, datetime, jmeter, beanshell

So I am trying to add 15 seconds to epoch time that I am collecting using the following code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
long now = cal.getTimeInMillis();
cal.add(Calendar.SECONDS, 15);

long then = cal.getTimeInMillis();
long secondsFromEpoch = (then + now) / 1000;

vars.put("secondsFromEpoch",seoncdsFromEpoch);
```

I have attempted to do this using the JSR223 PreProcessor in Jmeter, and I have also tried the Beanshell Preprocessor. The variable I have created in the code to use inside of Jmeter is not returning any results. This makes me assume there is something wrong with the code.

Is there anything noticeably incorrect in what I have written? Or is there another route I can take to get epoch time in seconds + 15 seconds ?

Comment: `(then + now)` is effectively the same as `2*now + 15000`. What's the meaning of "`2 * now`"?

Comment: Why the javaxcript tag? Java and JavaScript are two very different languages, so please choose.

Comment: Javascript is also used in Jmeter - this question was focusing on Jmeter functionality moreso than the language itself. Java, Groovy, Javascript, are all languages that fall under the Jmeter application.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) instance from the time you collected:

```
Long epochMillisYouCollected = ...
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochYouCollected);
```

then plus 15 seconds and return seconds from epoch:

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = instant.plusSeconds(15).getLong(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you aware or [__timeShift() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-dates-in-jmeter-using-the-timeshift-function)? You can add 15 seconds to current timestamp and store it into a variable as simple as `${__timeShift(,,P15S,,secondsFromEpoch)}`

---

If for any reason you want to continue scripting, there are (at least) 4 problems with your code:

1. My expectation is that you should change `Calendar.SECONDS` to [Calendar.SECOND](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#SECOND)
2. Your variable names are not the same, i.e. in one place you have `secondsFromEpoch`, in another `seoncdsFromEpoch`
3. You cannot use [Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) as an argument to `vars.put()` function, go for one of the following:

   ```
   vars.put("secondsFromEpoch",String.valueOf(secondsFromEpoch));
   ```

   or

   ```
   vars.putObject("secondsFromEpoch", secondsFromEpoch);
   ```
4. You're using Beanshell while [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). The equivalent Groovy code would be something like:

   ```
   use (groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
       def plus15seconds = new Date() + 15.seconds
       vars.put('secondsFromEpoch', plus15seconds.getTime() as String)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I believe you are after

```
    long secondsFromEpoch = Instant.now().plusSeconds(15).getEpochSecond();
```

### What went wrong?

You are adding two millisecond values, both counted from the 1970 epoch. This does not make sense and gives you a time in the future roughly double as long from the epoch as today. When I ran your code just now, I got 3 077 271 068 seconds, which according to Epoch Unix Time Stamp Converter equals 07/07/2067 @ 1:31pm (UTC).

### I suggest you don’t use the outdated classes

The date and time classes you were using — `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar` and `Date` — are not only long outdated, they also have design problems, particularly the first is notoriously troublesome. I recommend you avoid all of them and use java.time instead.

### Links

- [Oracle Tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)
- [Epoch Unix Time Stamp Converter](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)